# Why my DIV is not showing up in mobile browser but shows on desktop browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, overlay

Very generic issue I am sure, and apologies for the title, but not sure how else to word this.

Background: VisualStudio 2022 preview, .Net 4.8, ASP.Net (not Core)

**index.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <style>
        iframe {
            position: absolute;
            border: solid ;
            border-width: 1px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            min-width: 855px;
            min-height: 465px;
        }
    </style>
    
    <div class="divCanvas">
        <canvas id="compass" height="230" width="230"></canvas>
    </div>

    <iframe id="if1" 
        src="https://awebsite">
    </iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

**CSS**

```
#compass {
    background: url("../images/compass2.png");
    background-size: cover;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.divCanvas
{
    z-index:99;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 525px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

So what we have here is a simple `<iframe>` showing me a website and using CSS and `<div>` I am overlaying a `<canvas>` object over the iframe, and yes in a specific *spot* so that it overlays an area of the iframe where I want it displayed, hence the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties.

Problem is, this only works on **desktop** browsers (all of them), but does nothing other than show the `iframe` in a mobile browser (all of them again). What's happened with my `<div>`?

Incidentally, the VS project generated a `ViewSwitcher.ascx` file, which I think is the issue here, but it doesn't stand out where in the code there is anything happening for mobile browsers.

Any ideas please? Should I be using the `ViewSwitcher` ascx file in some way to display my `div` over the `iframe`? I have no idea what `viewswitcher` is really doing here in the first place or if it's even needed.

Thanks

Comment: The div goes off-screen with the given margin ..?

Comment: Hi @Teemu no it doesn't margin left and right are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in lack of design. Basically, I was missing the `Site.Mobile.Master` mobile version of the `Site.Master` file, and I had to include the reference to the same CSS for the desktop version. Yes, I wanted the mobile version to act like the desktop!

> <webopt:bundlereference

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Mobile.master.cs" Inherits="mysite.Site_Mobile" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/ViewSwitcher.ascx" TagPrefix="friendlyUrls" TagName="ViewSwitcher" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60" />

    <title>mywebsite</title>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </section>
            <friendlyUrls:ViewSwitcher runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```